# cygwin memory limit for sym2 composer install

Tags: php, windows, symfony, cygwin

Like so many others, I'm trying and failing at running composer on windows (to install my symfony2 dependencies).

Running with a memory-limit-flag like this doesn't have any effect.
php -d memory_limit=1024M /usr/local/bin/composer.phar

Nor does changing the php.ini file.

It appears though that the php.ini settings are cached in the cygwin program, because I can even change the name of my php.ini in the cygwin etc folder, and I still get the same results.

Is there a way to clear the cygwin cache, or restart it, or read the settings from php.ini into the program anew?

Comment: You can just run `php composer.phar ...` on Windows, or you can set that as an environment PATH variable - I've got composer happily running through Windows CMD on an old Win7 box - no need for Cygwin at all.

Comment: Might also be worth bearing in mind that PHP CLI can use a different *.ini* file to PHP running as an Apache module (for example) - make sure you're editing the correct *.ini* file. You can run `php --ini` to find out which is being used in CLI mode.

Comment: Have you tried `COMPOSER_MEMORY_LIMIT=-1 composer install` ?